# Relation return mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the problem with relations between Meal and MealGroup. Hibernate return me: "mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property".
I have two entities:

I tried remove @Join Column and mappedBy. Additional table was created, but I would like to JoinColumn.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Meal {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private int Id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meal")
    private List<Product> products;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meal_group_id")
    private MealGroup mealGroup;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class MealGroup {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private int Id;

    private String groupName;

    private LocalDateTime time;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meal_group")
    private List<Meal> meals;
}
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use class member name in `mappedBy`.

```java
//MealGroup class
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mealGroup")
private List<Meal> meals;
```